# Platform.runLater doesn't stop

Tags: java, javafx

In an controller, I have an

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    }
```

.... code which call a method with this code :

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Authentify.fxml"));
AuthentifyController ac = new AuthentifyController();
ac.setVocale(true);
fxmlLoader.setController(ac);

Pane containeur = (Pane)((Button) this.button3).getParent();
Pane newLoadedPane = fxmlLoader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(newLoadedPane);
Stage appStage = (Stage) this.button3.getScene().getWindow();
appStage.setScene(scene);

appStage.show();
```

The new `Scene` is started, but the `Platform.runLater` code is restarted at the same time

Could you say how to avoid `Platform.runLater` `Runnable` restart (stop it when the new scene is starting) ?

Complete class code here : https://framadrop.org/r/3e1SJpy3BL#QBiSWA9Qh0niQi3Qs1GIIv5aYTxi0KR2CNJgDSgEJBQ=

Comment: This is non-standard behavior almost certainly caused by some code not shown in the question. Create a [mcve] and add it to the question.

Comment: Complete class code here : https://framadrop.org/r/3e1SJpy3BL#QBiSWA9Qh0niQi3Qs1GIIv5aYTxi0KR2CNJgDSgEJBQ=

Comment: The MCVE needs to be part of the question. [Edit] it and include your code...

Comment: Please help, I must have a working code to valid my semester